# Javascript - Download image via XHR

Tags: javascript, dom, download, xmlhttprequest, pug

I'm currently trying to implement a download button that downloads all of the images in a list. My issue is that despite the fact that the download takes place and downloads all the items from my list, some images will be corrupted and other images would be duplicate. From all images only the last image in the list is downloaded correctly, however it seems that if I have 3 images in my list, two images will be a duplicate of the last item in the last and 1 image will be corrupted.

I have tried various things to get this to work but unfortunately none worked. I'd really appreciate your help.

html - this is actually pug, but I'm basically looping through the list items to display the relevant image

```
each pictureUrl in pictureUrls
    li.splide__slide
       img(class="picture-download" src='' + pictureUrl + '')
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('downloadMemo').addEventListener('click', function(){
    const pictureElements = document.getElementsByClassName('picture-download')
    for(let i=0;i<pictureElements.length;i++) {
        let pictureElement = pictureElements[i];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = (event) => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([xhr.response]));
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'PictureMemo-'+ (i+1) +'.jpg');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        };
        xhr.open('GET', pictureElement.getAttribute('src'));
        xhr.send();
    }
})
```

Comment: does using `let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` instead of `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` help? with `var` you're clobbering `xhr` a lot in that loop because of scope issues (var is function scoped, let is block scoped) that may solve all your problems ...

Comment: I'm speechless. That worked man, thanks a lot!

Comment: it's odd, you had `let i` and `let pictureElement` ... otherwise, if they were `var` your mess would've been bigger :p